# Quick and easy way to get around Docker's architecture image specifications?

Tags: docker

One of the reasons that we switched to Docker a few months back was to eliminate the need of having to maintain VMs with our latest tools, etc. Figured Docker would be a lot easier to just simply pull down the image and get going. However, it's become quite a pain lately.

Doesn't run in a Windows VM (because of lack of nested VM support and requires days of troubleshooting), getting it running in RHEL has become quite painful (with some saying Docker and RHEL don't work well together), and now I'm running into a platform support issue with the Raspberry Pi 4.

When trying to run my container on the Raspberry Pi 4, it's now telling me that the container's architecture doesn't match the host's architecture.

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested
```

A little confusing because I was hoping Docker would give us a lot more flexibility and compatibility with our customer platforms, but it seems to be quite painful.

From my understanding, we have to re-build the entire container and push out arm containers to arm systems, and amd64 to others?

Is there not just a quick and dirty workaround that I can use to get the container to run and ignore the architecture?

Comment: No, there is no q&d solution. it's a different processor -- code compiled for one processor cannot run on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shared v.s. Simple Tag

To indirectly address the issue you mentioned, you can use a `shared tag` that is multi-platform. You can see the difference [here](https://github.com/docker-library/faq#whats-the-difference-between-shared-and-simple-tags).

An example:

> - The "Simple Tags" enable `docker run mongo:4.0-xenial` to "do the right thing" across architectures on a single platform (Linux in the case of mongo:4.0-xenial).
> - The "Shared Tags" enable `docker run mongo:4.0` to roughly work on both Linux and as many of the various versions of Windows that are supported

### Force platform

To directly address the issue you mentioned, this warning HAS happened before to others. Check out the following [bitwarden docker discussion](https://github.com/dani-garcia/bitwarden_rs/discussions/1264#discussioncomment-607685). The fix is to force the platform when using docker run, like so:

```
docker run --platform linux/arm64 image_name_or_id
```

Make sure `--platform` argument is defined before the image name/id.

### Building multi-platform images

1. docker run `--platform` parameter was added [probably here](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5767) but not to the docs! It's shown when you run `docker run --help`

> platform string: Set platform if server is multi-platform capable

2. [Multi-Platform Docker Builds](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/)
3. [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks so much for the input! Looking into this now!

Comment: Updated my answer.